# Export function prompt to text

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, text, export

I have created a certain function that is printing text through "print".
i want to store that prompt to a text file.

the function name is "printall(x)".

I have tried the following

```
text_file = open('newfile.txt', 'w')
text_file.write(printall(x))
text_file.close
```

this did not work.

how can I make it happen?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want to store the output of the function to a file?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, do: `import sys` at the top of your code.

Then, in your `printall(x)` method, you should add the following as your first line:

`sys.stdout = open('newfile.txt', 'w')`

Then, whenever you do print, it will write the code to the file instead of the console.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's best to save `sys.stdout` to a variable before assigning a file object to it. That way you can reassign the original value of `sys.stdout` to `sys.stdout`, in case you want to use `print` in its normal fashion later.

Comment: This is working, the problem is that i'm inside a "for loop", so what i get is just the last item written into 'newfile.txt'. I want each one to be written to the same file. how is that possible to do?

Comment: @user3594227, If my answer was helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thank you

Comment: @JustinBarber, No need, just do: `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` when you want to switch back

Comment: @sshashank124 `sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__` does *not* switch `sys.stdout` back to its original value.

Comment: This is working, the problem is that i'm inside a "for loop", so what i get is just the last item written into 'newfile.txt'. I want each one to be written to the same file. how is that possible to do?

Comment: @user3594227, In that case, change 'w' to 'a'

Comment: @user3594227, No problem. Best of luck with your code.